# Read documents in order

Tags: xquery, marklogic, marklogic-10

We have a list of URIs and which we need to read in the sequence in which it is passed.

**Example1**

```
doc(("/doc1", "/doc2", "/doc3"))
```

above function should return the content of "/doc1" then "/doc2" and then "/doc3" but it is not happening.

The same thing is happening is with the below query also.

**Example2**

```
cts:search(doc(), cts:document-query((("/doc1"),("/doc2"),("/doc3"))))
```

What will be the solution if I want to read the documents in which sequence I pass the URIs ?

Any help is appreciated..!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`cts:search` has its own ordering functionality, which you can trigger using functions like [`cts:index-order`](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:index-order). `fn:doc` takes an array, and will return them in database order. Neither of them sounds like what you are trying to achieve.

I would suggest explicitly iterating over the uris, and fetching the uris one by one. You could use `!` operator for this, for instance:

```
("/doc1", "/doc2", "/doc3") ! doc(.)
```

HTH!

Answer (score 4):

@grtjn's answer is correct but you could reduce it to one database query and just return the docs in the order that you want with something like

```
let $uris := ("/doc2", "/doc1", "/doc3")

let $docs := map:new(
  fn:doc($uris) ! map:entry(xdmp:node-uri(.), .)
)

for $i in $uris
return map:get($docs, $i)
```

Comment: Or the query can do the sort using the Optic API, as in 
op.fromLexicons({uri: cts.uriReference()}, null, op.fragmentIdCol('docId'))
.where(op.gt(op.col('uri'), lastUriInPreviousPage))
.orderBy('uri')
.limit(256)
.joinDoc('doc', 'docId')
.result();